# Schema recommendation for having same account for different websites sharing same database?

Tags: database, database-design, schema, entity-relationship

I really need to get some database design help. I have a platform where we have a table called users. It has a column called role for defining whether its a customer, provider, manager. But column email is unique. So at first we thought that its okay clients will make new emails. But then later it was not formidable. They wanted to use same email for both platform (Just like google single email for everything) So I want to really know the very basic idea of how Google maintains it. What should be the very basic db schema for it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to break out roles from the user table.

If you are able to go this route;

user table - email as the primary key
platform table - platform id/name as the primary key
user/platform table - combination of email/platform id as the primary key

This will give you the ability to store and query when users have multiple platforms and/or roles.